# re_comm build error in roboearth installation (ROS Fuerte + Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, roboearth, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to install RoboEarth within ROS Fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04. I looked over all answers concerning roboearth installation errors but found nothing like this. My installation fails when building the last package, namely re_comm. Can anyone help me? This is the relevant output:

```
[rosmake-0] Finished >> re_comm [ make ]                                       
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_comm: 403.8 sec ]        [ 1 Active 102/103 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Export of model for Cop ID "+req.object_id+" failed.", null, null);
                    ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:437: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                    CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("Requesting model for object '"+req.object_name+"' from RoboEarth...", "", null, "roboearth.png");
                    ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:460: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                        CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Object model download finished.\n\n"+targetFolderFile.getName(), null, null);
                        ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:513: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                            CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("Sending model for object '"+req.object_name+"' to the vision system...\n\n"+xmlFileName, "", null, "cop.png");
                            ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:523: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                            CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "Object model "+xmlFileName+" received.", null, null);
                            ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:536: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                        CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "No model for "+req.object_name+" found.", null, null);
                        ^
  /home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java:548: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable CommunicationVisApplet
  location: class roboearth.wp1.UnizarRoboEarthInterface.RetrieveCopModelCallback
                CommunicationVisApplet.visualizeCommunication("", "No model for "+req.object_name+" found.", null, null);
                ^
  42 errors
  make[3]: *** [../bin/roboearth/wp5/CopRoboEarthInterface.class] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_java_compile_1_68.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/asimo/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_comm written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/asimo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130108-200745/re_comm/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51730/re_comm-build-error-in-roboearth-installation-(ros-fuerte-+-ubuntu-12.04)/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in another answer, it seems like its due to some refactoring in KnowRob.

So after you checkout the latest source code into your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as described by  @mortiz.

(I have not checked if this would work without the new package... you may try replacing the import line first before attempting to pull in knew knowrob)

```
svn co http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest knowrob
```

Replace the following import line with the one below it in the files which are causing this problem:

```
import de.tum.in.fipm.kipm.gui.visualisation.applets.CommunicationVisApplet; //delete

import edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.vis.applets.CommunicationVisApplet; //add

/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp5/CopRoboEarthInterface.java
/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp5/REClients.java
/roboearth/re_comm/src/roboearth/wp1/UnizarRoboEarthInterface.java
```

---

Originally posted by [alexiip](https://answers.ros.org/users/1533/alexiip/) with karma: 71 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is related to a refactoring in the KnowRob stack that changed some namespaces. You may need to install KnowRob from source by checking it out somewhere into your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:

svn co http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest knowrob

Otherwise you can also just comment out those lines where 'CommunicationVisApplet' appears.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alexiip](https://answers.ros.org/users/1533/alexiip/) on 2013-02-17**:
Pulling new code did not seem to fix it. I guess commenting out is the only way.